# Visual C# Simulating F12 keypress at certain time of day

Tags: c#

My friend has asked me to create a program that will press F12 for him at a certain time of day.

This is an unusual request and I was wondering how to get Visual C# to send the F12 request and at a certain time.  Maybe it's better to implement a program that presses F12 automatically and set it up in task scheduler?  I don't know.

I think the ideal would just have the program run in the background and hit the key at the certain time.  I don't know how to instruct Visual C# to send the F12 key.  Also, I don't know how to set up things to go off at certain times.

Can someone help me out or point me to a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [Windows Input Simulator Library](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator)

```
public static void Main()
{
     InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
}
```

only thing you need to do is compiling your code into executable and then adding it to **Windows Task Scheduler** as Task.

or alternatively you can use native Windows API under `User32.dll`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; // key down flag
public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; // key up flag
public const int F12 = 123; // F12 key code

public static void Main()
{ 
    keybd_event(F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0); // press F12 down
    keybd_event(F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // release F12

}
```

again use Windows task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`keybd_event`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event).
Here is a sample code that illustrates how to use it.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    public const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; // key down flag
    public const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; // key up flag
    public const int F12 = 123; // F12 key code

    public static void Main()
    {
        const int hour = 4;
        const int min = 15;

        // Get DateTime at which the key is supposed to be pressed
        DateTime nextCertainTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(hour).AddMinutes(min);

        // If it is already too late for today, add 1 day (set to tomorrow)
        if (nextCertainTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            nextCertainTime = nextCertainTime.AddDays(1);
        }

        // Calculate the remaining time
        TimeSpan remainingTime = nextCertainTime - DateTime.Now;

        // Wait until "certain time"
        Thread.Sleep((int)remainingTime.TotalMilliseconds);

        keybd_event(F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0); // press F12 down
        keybd_event(F12, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // release F12
    }
}
```

If you want to do this repeatedly, just put it into a `while (true)` loop and add 1 day to `nextCertainTime` with each iteration.

It would be better to use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead, but it is not as easy to set up.

Alternatively, it is also possible to use [`SendKeys.Send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `keybd_event`, but it is a bit of an overkill for pressing a single key.

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{F12}");
```

If you decide to use Task Scheduler, as suggested in another answer, you might as well consider using something more appropriate than C#.

Perhaps an AHK script, which could be as simple as this:

```
Send {F12}
```

Comment: This is what I came up with ```using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace sendF12
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SendKeys.Send("{F12}");
}
}
}```

Comment: @ev1lchris That seems similar to the second option I've mentioned, although it's not particularly intuitive to give a label an on-click event.

Comment: I did that by accident

Comment: @ev1lchris Okay, so, has the problem been solved then? If so, you should probably mark this question as answered.

Comment: I'm not sure. Don't really know how to test it.

Comment: @ev1lchris I assume you wanted to know how to do this for some reason. You can just try if it works. That sounds like a pretty sensible way to test it.

Comment: How do I close this question?

Comment: @ev1lchris You accept an answer by clicking the check tick button (below the votes on the left of the question).